# JS: How to postpone execution of a function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

Trying to mount a Vue.js component, but seems the second function (`eventSelection`) is being called earlier then expected. What should I do to make it execute only after the first function is finished?

```
...
mounted() {
  this.getAllEvents()
  this.eventSelection()
},

methods: {
  getAllEvents: function () {
    console.log("Cheguei aqui");
    getEvents()
    .then( function (res) {
      console.log("Entrei then")
      this.events = res.data
    }.bind(this))
    .catch( function (err){
      debugger;
      console.error('WeekSimulation, getEvents() ', err)
      this.events = ["Seu chefe o convida para um happy hour com os diretores no final do expediente.  Ao mesmo tempo, você recebe uma mensagem de seu cônjuge lembrando da apresentação no colégio do seu filho. O que você faz?", "Você tem muito trabalho a fazer, porém o tempo com sua família anda escasso. No final do expediente você escolheria jantar com sua família ou fazer hora extra?",
                         "Você acorda de manhã e seu filho não está se sentindo bem. Ao verificar sua agenda, lembra que tem uma reunião com um novo cliente em uma hora. Você leva seu filho ao médico ou vai para a reunião?", 
                         "Ao checar o seu celular durante uma reunião com os diretores de sua organização, nota que recebeu cinco ligações de seu cônjuge. Você continua na reunião, ou pede para atender o telefone?"]
    }.bind(this))
  },

  eventSelection: function() {
    console.log("Funcao de selecao de evento")
    debugger;
    this.selectedEvent = _.shuffle(this.events)[0]
    console.log(this.selectedEvent)
  }      

}
...
```

Comment: points for effort, but it's a bit bloated no?

Comment: set this.events to result of getEents like so: `this.events=getEents().then(d=>d.data)` and in eventSelection: `this.events.then(events=>this.selectedEvent = _.shuffle(this.events)[0])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return the `getEvents()` promise from `getAllEvents()` so you can chain another `then()` to it and call `eventSelection()` after getEvents() resolves

```
mounted() {
  this.getAllEvents().then(this.eventSelection)

},

methods: {
  getAllEvents: function () {
   // return the promise
   return getEvents()
    .then( function (res) {
      ....
    }.bind(this))


}
```

Also make sure to add `return this.events` in the `catch` in order to resolve the initial promise

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `promises()`.
I couldn't comprehend your code, my apologies, here's a generic example:

```
first = function(){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    console.log("first running");
    deferred.resolve();  // <----------resolve the deferred
    return deferred.promise();
}

second = function(){
    console.log("second running..sigh..");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    first().then(second);

});
```

Comment: `promise()` the answer the, OP.  Listen to this guy

Comment: OP's code already uses promises or you wouldn't have `then()` methods

Answer (score -2):

Use a simple callback:

```
 mounted() {
   this.getAllEvents(this.eventSelection);
 }

 getAllEvents: function (cb) {
    ...
    cb();
 },

  eventSelection: function() {
   ...
  }
```

Comment: `getAllEvents` doesn't execute any callback functions